# How can I generate dynamic cron in nodeJs from inputs date given

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cron

I have a usecase where unsure how to generate cron using which lib in nodejs.

**Edit** - Just a note here, I am using [Agenda lib](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) And using this lib, I am trying to schedule custom event trigger.

**Edit-2** - I am using date picker with react to pick up the dates, and logic will handle on the backend for scheduling with Agenda lib.

I am using node express with react where I have requirement to schedule a recurring events.

[image]

Here's picture where I have save the data with cron, How can I achieve this?
any suggestions or node lib?

Comment: Are you talking about crone jobs? if so this library might be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=node-cron

Comment: I am already using agenda lib for such events, but now I want to generate cron dynamically using date and time picker from front end. And make cron out of it.

Comment: @TechNerd you found any solution for dynamic scheduling?

Answer (score 3):

If cron-like functionality from within Node is what you want, you can try [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

```js
const cron = require("node-cron");
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

app = express();

frequency="Yearly"
pattern=""

switch(frequency) {
  case "Daily":
    pattern = "0 0 * * *"
    break;
  case "Monthly":
    pattern = "0 0 1 * *"
    break;
  default:
    pattern = "* * * * *"
    frequency = "every minute"
}

// schedule tasks to be run on the server
cron.schedule(pattern, function () {
  console.log("running a task " + frequency);
});

app.listen(3128);
```

Example borrowed from here [Node.js Cron Jobs By Examples](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples)

Added some extra switch case logic to demonstrate a possible workflow for your task at hand.

Comment: Hello Arch, I am already using Agenda lib, where I have to scheudle trigger from frontend with date picket as per the image in the question above.

Comment: Hi @TechNerd, have you checked any of the examples available in the documentation? https://github.com/agenda/agenda. How is this interface generated? Can you please update your question with further details?

Comment: Updated, Mostly I am using date picker to pick the time and date. And thinking to make a cron pattern and save to Agenda. But not sure how to generate cron from the date picker data. I can make certain Daily, Weekly, Monthly, custom type and process the date and time accordingly. But How'd I generate cron? Also confused the use case at Monthly, How can I save that?

Comment: @TechNerd May be you may refer to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-time-generator, package. To generate cron expression as per the date picked up.